# Cleaner way to make the controller's setter explicitly propagate the change to the CALayer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158772/is-there-way-to-keep-a-text-view-and-a-slider-in-sync-to-a-cgrects-float-value-w) asked for a way to keep a text view and slider in sync with bindings when modifying a CGRect's "x" value.

Following Peter Hosey's advice on using the controller's setter to propogate those changes to the CALayer, I came up with the following:

```
@interface WindowController : NSObject {
  CALayer *layer;
  float frameOriginX;
}
@end

@implementation WindowController
...
-(void)setFrameOriginX:(id)value {
  [layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value floatValue]] 
       forKeyPath:@"frame.origin.x"];
  frameOriginX = [value floatValue];

}

-(float)frameOriginX {
 return [[layer valueForKeyPath:@"frame.origin.x"]floatValue];
}
@end
```

I used bindings to connect the text view and slider to "self.frameOriginX" and it's all working–both controls update each other. However, I was wondering what a cleaner way to do this is.

Thank You,

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why does `setFrameOriginX:` take an `id` and `frameOriginX` return a `float`? KVC will not like this. Plus, you should use `CGFloat`, not `float`.

Once you fix that, you're in luck. Today, [Colin Barrett released SSGeometryKVC](https://bitbucket.org/cbarrett/ssgeometrykvc/). With that, your setter becomes:

```
-(void)setFrameOriginX:(CGFloat)newX {
    frameOriginX = newX;
    [[layer mutableRectValueForKey:@"frame"].x = frameOriginX;
}
```

Note that neither this implementation nor your original implementation is thread-safe. This won't be a problem as long as it's only the controls that are calling it.

> I used bindings to connect the text view and slider to "self.frameOriginX"…

Huh? If you bound them to the controller, you don't need `self.` here.

Comment: Thank you again Peter. Your help is very much appreciated.